# Main Page Background Image Slider Question

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript to change a background image on a page. It works, but there is a minor problem. For a split second, between images there is nothing (just white screen). Again it lasts just a split second but it is annoying.

How can I get one image to fade out while the other is fading in?

I've tried adjusting the fadeIn and fadeOut time, but I realized the second image doesn't start to fadeIn until the first completely fades out.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

     var imgArr = new Array(   
     'images/home/background_image_1.jpg',  
     'images/home/background_image_2.jpg',  
     'images/home/background_image_3.jpg'
     );

     var preloadArr = new Array();  
     var i;

     /* preload images */  
     for(i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++){  
     preloadArr[i] = new Image();  
     preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];  
     }

     var currImg = 1;  
     var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 20000);

     /* image rotator */  
     function changeImg(){  
     $('#background-image').fadeOut(1500, function(){  
     $(this).css('background','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +')')

   .css("background-position", "center").css("background-repeat", "no-repeat").css("background-size", "cover");  
     }).fadeIn(1500);
     }

     });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749708/fade-in-fade-out-background-images-without-white-background

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's `.fadeOut()` has optional parameters `.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete callback ] )`.

Where `complete callback` is the function that will run when the fading animation is done. So that split second is actually the `duration` you've passed to your `.fadeOut()` function.

Your code takes `1.5s` to perform the animation and then only when it's done then it calls your function that fades in another background image. That's what causing the delay.

An alternative option would be to create seperate executions of `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`. And please don't apply the images on the same element, because you won't achieve it that way. You will need to create an `<img>` for each picture and set `position: absolute` on them to position them on top of each other. and then apply fade animation on each `<img>`

You might need this for revision [here](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: Actually that's what I thought, thanks for the clarification. I sincerely appreciate you taking the time to respond

Comment: Yes, you thought right @wfarrar . No problem, we're all here to help each other... :).